# Program won't quit if user enters -1 while using return 0;

Tags: c++, return

Here's one of the return 0; sections I have in my main() function:

```
cout << "Would you like to remove a Pokemon? (Y/N): ";
cin >> removePokemonChoice;
cin.ignore(5, '\n');
if (toupper(removePokemonChoice) == 'Y')
{
    deletePokemon();
    cout << "New list:" << endl;
    displayPokemon();
}
if (removePokemonChoice == -1)
    return 0;
```

currently, it won't exit out of the program if the user enters -1. I can't use an else statement because I want the program to loop (there's a similar question after this bit that I want to come after) until -1 is entered.

Comment: "-1" is two characters, so it doesn't fit into a `char` to begin with. If you want to let the user enter an integer or a character, you're going to have to read into something that can hold either (like a string) and then do extra work to get what you need.

Comment: Okay, so if I change my removePokemonChoice to a string, do I need to change cin to getline and remove the cin.ignore? I started to use a getline for this in class but my teacher said I should use a char. The toupper function doesn't work with strings (to my understanding) @chris

Comment: No, you don't, as you still don't need a whole line. A string of length 1 is a lot like a `char`, too. In that case, `str[0]` *is* a character that represents the entire string. If your teacher said to use a `char`, then that's probably what you should do, but I would double check on the whole entering -1 to quit in that case, as it's possible, but honestly kind of ugly.

Comment: Oh duh. Yeah, a single digit makes more sense. We've used -1 to quit in class before so that was my default. Using zero works fine. But now it's telling me "expect 'while' before '(' token." There's a do at the top and a while at the bottom. any way to eliminate this? There's another statement just like the one I posted after this one, (so two more if statements) @chris

Comment: Could be mismatched braces. I have no clue.

Comment: Dang it I forgot the braces. It's not my night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program asks "(Y/N)" so I suppose `removePokemonChoice` is a `char` type... it is strange to expect -1 value from `char` data. By the way "-1" need 2 characters, so it must be string :-)

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:

You're writing a program that asks you whether or not you want to remove a Pokemon. Normally, like in the actual game itself when Prof. Oak prompts you with a confirmation of do you want Charmander (and the answer is yes, you always go with the fire type, no exceptions). The choices the game will always give you is "Yes" or "No".

Would you ask a yes/no question and expect a numerical answer back? While it is true the compiler converts and does numerical stuff in the background, what you really should be thinking about is, is it intuitive to the user?